# Installing and Updating MongoDB: Dev x Prod Envs

Tags: mongodb

I'm playing with MongoDB while reading O'Reilly MongoDB - The Definitive Guide.

In appendix A, the authors teach how to install MongoDB, downloading the latest version, creating a /data/db directory and so on.

The question is: what's the best approach to install MongoDB?

In my computer, first I extracted the archive and then, inside /mongodb-linux-i686-2.0.1 directory, I created that structure, /data/db. Did I take the right decision?

I'm just playing but, what if I decide to start a real project using MongoDB? How to setup properly my server, in order to update MongoDB for next releases without data loss (as my /data directory is inside /mongodb-linux-i686-2.0.1 directory)?

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily MongoDB will use `/data/db` -- that is, that folder in the root of your filesystem tree -- as the data path. You can override this with the `--dbpath` command-line argument, or in a config file (and with `--config`). It is up to you whether to use the default data path or a custom one, and to use a startup script that sets the options you want.

If you are using an RPM-based distribution, see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CentOS+and+Fedora+Packages for information about using officially-provided 10gen RPMs; if you are using Debian or Ubuntu, see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages instead. These packages come with startup scripts for you and defaults for `--dbpath` which match expectations of the respective operating systems.

Comment: Thinking in the Future, how can I properly update MongoDB if my /data directory is "inside" MongoDB directory?